# Is it possible to relate two CodeFluent collections at run-time?

Tags: codefluent

I'm looking for a way to link seemingly unrelated CodeFluent collections at run-time without having defined a relation  between the entities (typename and relationpropertyname of each property would not be set) in the CodeFluent modeler. Each entity would have a common key value.

I could convert the collections to DataTables, add them to a DataSet, and create the relations in the DataSet; but then I would have to convert the data back to their related CF entity.  This would be a bit messy.  I'd rather let CodeFluent BOM handle everything.

Comment: The relation concept in CodeFluent Entities is very closely related to the relation in the database. Nothing prevents you from creating a CustomerId property (not key) in the Order entity, w/o defining a relation, but then you won't have any stored procedure + BOM method created either. The question is really why do you want to avoid declaring a relation?

Comment: I have a number of related tables in different databases.  These tables in turn have related tables.  Since many of these tables are in geographically diverse stores and in different servers, if I relate all of the tables in the model, it become unwieldy.  I was hoping to programmatically graft in related CF collections depending on the data requirements at that moment such that the resultant collections could be displayed in a hierarchical grid.

Comment: Likewise, as the user drills down and would like to graft another related table, it could be done of the fly so to speak.  This way, the tables and their records would be handled in the application like any CF entity and thus not requiring extensive programming to figure out record state, conversion from/to CF collection, and circumventing the persistent layer.

Comment: There's nothing built-in in the product that would add "useful code" between classes generated from two different models. However if this is a common pattern between your entities/models, you could write an aspect that would add that.

Comment: Hi Simon,  Thank you for answering my question!